# For vim, how to get the what autocmd events are occurring when some action is taking

Tags: vim

I checked the vim help for autocmd-event, but cannot identify which events are mapping those specific actions, such as c(change), or multi-replace in command mode for example (:1,$s/abc/ABC/g), and delete (dw, x, backspace, dd) and a(append). I only found InertEnter is for before entering I mode.

Why I asked for this is that I need to add some text/record to track the changes for the edited file in vim and these text/record will be saved in this edited file.

Thanks!

EDIT: is there any way to let vim print the events that are occurring when doing some actions to edit a file?

Answer (score 2):

You can diff current buffer and the original file via au BufWritePre to do some sort of tracking. [Also see this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-vim-script-5/).

Comment: thanks, but I need a real time tracking, that is, when I was changing a line, there would be adding a new line "add lines\n" on top of it to indicate this was new added line in current file.

Comment: add again, why my at message was removed in previous comment?

Comment: The archive of the above dead link https://web.archive.org/web/20190228120833/https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-vim-script-5/. In summary, it adds one hook function to track.

Answer (score 1):

Doing any of the operations in your question doesn't fire any event.

I can't imagine a method that doesn't involve something like the `CursorHold` event and comparing the current state of the buffer against a previous state.